# Change text of certain ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, getview

I am aware that there are multiple `ListView` projects with powerful list views which can display cute headers.

However, I don't need such complexity. All I need is to insert a simple `TextView` above certain list items. So I tried to do this in `getView` method of the `BaseAdapter`

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

            //set title accordingly
            if (position == 0 ) {
                //insert some text here
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "getView position = " + position);
        }

        TextView txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);        
        txt.setText("some text comes here");

        return convertView;
    }
```

However, although this code was supposed to change only the text of the first item, it also changes the text of another items randomly. There are like 20 items in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the view recycling - The specific view you add the text is being used down the list when you scroll, as it's been recycled.

What you should do is

```
if (position == 0 ) {
    //add the text
} else {
    //remove the text
}
```

To clarify, you should do this outside the convertView==null if statement - it should happen on every getView, not only when creating a fresh view.

Edit: Come to think of it, if you only need a text above the first item, why not use

```
listView.addHeaderView(v);
```

It might give you what you need.

Comment: Put it outside, but random still happens. I change text to first item, then again to other ones randomly.

Comment: Since everything is recycled you must always undo your changes in the `else` part. As a general rule any code inside a `getView()' 'if' statement should have the opposing effect under an 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

ListView items are recycled. You can not manually edit an item you must edit the data that represents the item. Your adapter should hold some data type that can be externally modified and then by calling [notifyDatasetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) the listview will redraw appropriately.

Sudo code:

```
class MyData {

    String normalText;
    String overrideText;

}

....

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        //set title accordingly
        if (position == 0 ) {
            //insert some text here
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getView position = " + position);
    }

    MyData data = getItem(position);

    TextView txtExtra = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.extratextview);
    txtExtra.setVisibility(data.overrideText == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    txtExtra.setText(data.overrideText == null ? "" : data.overrideText);

    TextView txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);        
    txt.setText(data.normalText);

    return convertView;
}
```